# cocos2dx shader rotate a shape in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader, cocos2d-x

This problem is cocos2d-x related since I am using cocos2d-x as game engine but I can think it can be solved use basic opengl shader knowledge.

Part 1:

. I have a canvas size of 800 * 600

. I try to draw a simple colored square in size of 96 * 96 which is placed in the middle of the canvas

It is quite simple, the draw part code :

```
var boundingBox = this.getBoundingBox();
var squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
var vertices = [
    boundingBox.width, boundingBox.height, 
    0,                 boundingBox.height,
    boundingBox.width, 0, 
    0,                 0
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

And the vert shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = CC_PMatrix * CC_MVMatrix * a_position;
}
```

And the frag shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec2 center;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float rotation;

void main()
{
    vec4 RED = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 GREEN = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = GREEN;
}
```

And everything works fine :

[image]

The grid line is size of 32 * 32, and the black dot indicates the center of the canvas.

Part 2:

. I try to separate the square into half (vertically)

. The left part is green and the right part is red

I changed the frag shader to get it done :

```
void main()
{
    vec4 RED = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 GREEN = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    /*
        x => [0, 1]
        y => [0, 1]
    */
    vec2 UV = (rotatedFragCoord.xy - center.xy + resolution.xy / 2.0) / resolution.xy;

    /* 
        x => [-1, 1]
        y => [-1, 1]
    */
    vec2 POS = -1.0 + 2.0 * UV;

    if (POS.x <= 0.0) {
        gl_FragColor = GREEN;
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = RED;
    }
}
```

The uniform 'center' is the position of the square so it is 400, 300 in this case.

The uniform 'resolution' is the content size of the square so the value is 96, 96.

The result is fine :

[image]

Part 3:

. I try to change the rotation in cocos2dx style

```
myShaderNode.setRotation(45);
```

And the square is rotated but the content is not :

[image]

So I tried to rotate the content according to the rotation angle of the node.

I changed the frag shader again:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 RED = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 GREEN = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec2 rotatedFragCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy - center.xy;
    float cosa = cos(rotation);
    float sina = sin(rotation);
    float t = rotatedFragCoord.x;
    rotatedFragCoord.x = t * cosa - rotatedFragCoord.y * sina + center.x;
    rotatedFragCoord.y = t * sina + rotatedFragCoord.y * cosa + center.y;

    /* 
        x => [0, 1]
        y => [0, 1]
    */
    vec2 UV = (rotatedFragCoord.xy - center.xy + resolution.xy / 2.0) / resolution.xy;

    /* 
        x => [-1, 1]
        y => [-1, 1]
    */
    vec2 POS = -1.0 + 2.0 * UV;

    if (POS.x <= 0.0) {
        gl_FragColor = GREEN;
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = RED;
    }
}
```

The uniform rotation is the angle the node rotated so in this case it is 45.

The result is close to what I want but still not right:

[image]

I tried hard but just can not figure out what is wrong in my code and what's more if there is anyway easier to get things done.

I am quite new to shader programming and any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `radians(rotation)`

Comment: Not related: it's better to avoid using conditional statements and loops in OpenGL shders, espicially fragment.